# How to divide the total sum from some row to some variable using DAX in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

im a newbie at the Power BI.

currently im facing a problem. I would like to divide the result from some rows into some variable.

I have some table, called SITE CHARGES, and PROJECT.

[image: SITE CHARGES]

[image: PROJECT]

And the problem is I cannot showing the charges for each Project. can you help me how to solve it using DAX or any solution ? thank you so much

the result expected result is like

[image: EXPECTED RESULT]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the project table create the following calculated column:

```
Avg = 
var thisID = [ID]
var tempSum = 
SUMX(
    FILTER(
        SUMMARIZE(
            'Site_Charges';
            [ID_Site];
            "SumAmount"; SUM('Site_Charges'[Amount])
        );
        [ID_Site] = thisID
    );
    [SumAmount]
)

var tempCount = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Project');
    ALL(Project);
    'Project'[ID] = thisID
)

return

 DIVIDE(tempSum;tempCount;0)
```

Then you end up with a column like this:

[image]

Comment: thank you for answering, but im sorry your answer is referring to the average of the product by project and that's why the PC2 is 450 when PC2 is supposed to be 900. what I expect is to show the cost for each project.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question, I've updated my answer. Please regard this as a new answer so please disregard anything I wrote in my previous.